# Getting AWS spot prices for spots with duration

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3

Is there an opportunity to collect prices for AWS Spot Blocks for Defined-Duration programmatically without parsing this page https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/pricing/ ?

It will be magically to have this ability in boto3, may be this 
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_spot_price_history method can ?

Comment: Yes, that is what `describe_spot_pricing` does, but in more detail.  What is your question, please?

Comment: You mean describe_spot_price_history() ? But it returns just prices for instance spots, not for defined-duration spot, that higher aprox. in 5-6 times.

Comment: Sorry, I was having trouble understanding your question.

Comment: Ok, let have a look into this page https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot/pricing/, in the 'spot instances' tab you can see the list of prices and this is the same prices that we can fetch using describe_spot_price_history(). BUT I want to fetch prices from the "Defined Duration for Linux" tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You apparently can't -- as of now -- fetch specified duration/spot block price history from the EC2 API.

> You can specify a duration of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6 hours. The price that you pay depends on the specified duration. To view the current prices for a 1 hour duration or a 6 hour duration, see Spot Instance Prices. You can use these prices to estimate the cost of the 2, 3, 4, and 5 hour durations. When a request with a duration is fulfilled, the price for your Spot instance is fixed, and this price remains in effect until the instance terminates.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/spot-requests.html#fixed-duration-spot-instances

This might change in the future.

For now, note that the actual price you pay will of course be at or below your bid price, but the price you'll pay is not determined until the instance launches.

Of course, **all** spot pricing (conventional or block) is only an estimate -- every spot request has the potential to cause a market shift, so regardless of what you see on the pricing history, if your bid is successful, it is likely to impact the market price upwards except in cases where supply exceeds demand, which is not the normal case for most instance types.  The price displayed on the pricing screens is what people are paying, now.